# How to change this to passive: No one knows when he has come into the room?

Tags: adverbs, clauses, when

How can I change this sentence to a passive one?

```
No one knows when he has come into the room.
```

I feel it is probably wrong to say

```
When he has come into the room is not known by anybody.  (wrong)
```

So what would be the right way, given that 'when' does not seem to  fit for introducing a adverbial clause? Thanks.

Comment: I'd use past simple instead of present perfect in this sentence.

Comment: The present perfect there is odd.  But your sentence is otherwise grammatical.  The passive is awkward but possible. That he has come into the room is not known by anyone. When he came into the room is not known by anybody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *It is not known when he has come into the room.*

Since "no one" knows, it doesn't seem necessary to specify *who* doesn't know, so I think this should work.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Do you know whether   there exists a word similar to 'when' which allows us to say something like "When he has come into the room is not known by anybody"? Here, I am looking for a proper adverb to replace "when" above so to make the sentence work.

Comment: Does it need to be an adverb? I think what would sound most natural would be "The time at which he came into the room is not known by anybody."